# Looking for a dystopian book with handicapped people

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

I read a short Dystopian story in middle school, with a society where everyone is equal. People are given mental and physical handicaps to make sure everyone is equal. A kid named Harrison (I think) tries to overthrow the government. He is huge and Godlike. He gets shot at the end. That's all I remember.

Comment: The term "handicapped" in this question does not refer to people with disabilities.  The reference is more like a golf handicap rather than a disability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Harrison Bergeron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrison_Bergeron) by Kurt Vonnegut.

From Wikipedia:

> The story was written as a satire to offer a critique on people's claims that we should all be equal It has been embraced by those critical of egalitarianism as an allegory of caution against socially enforced equality, more specifically the dangers of enforcing equality by virtue of leveling

And I'd be willing to bet that this question has been asked before.

Comment: so what if its been asked before. if its story identification, it shouldn't matter. i am actually trying to find the answer to this. its not like its an actual question (by that i mean its not a question about scify, its one finding it) .